# Dynamic form designer in .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wpf, silverlight-5.0

I want to create an application which allows the user to create dynamic insurance forms, having fields like label,textbox,textarea,date,dropdown etc & styles like underline,font, size etc. After user creates these forms they will be launched from web application where user can fill in the insurance details for customer & then export them in pdf.

I need wide opinion on what is the best way to achieve this. My thought process is to have WPF application with drag & drop support to design forms & then serialize the xaml in database. Have a silverlight web application which will render that xaml(in short show that form) for user to fill in & then export. I explored wufoo & other form designers but they don't fit in my requirement. I was also searching for jquery plugins but not sure if they will be good fit for here.

Comment: You can easily do this in WPF. And it would be as extensive as you like. You can also take a look at the `SharpDevelop` open source code. Maybe you can get useful stuff from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can build dynamic form designer using **jquery**

see this link http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/

after design form ..store html in database and populate it to browser for data entry. you can use html and post data on server by **jquery**

I have already create this kind of application for design form ..publish them for data entry and store data..

Comment: Thanks @sangram. This is really cool, but not as extensible as I am looking for, basically most of my insurance forms have rich facility like underline, center aligned, left aligned etc. then there are page headers & footers. Ultimately after rending the form to client when the policy detail is filled that need to be exported to pdf(ITextSharp is one option).I am also evaluating adobe livecycle.